# find the hidden URL request a website is making after form submission, for Scraping

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to **scrape** data from https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/tmrpublicsearch/frmmain.aspx using BeautifulSoup. But the request this website is making to fetch data is not visible. (Example: If we enter "Yahoo" as Wordmark and "9" as Class. It redirects to URL https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/tmrpublicsearch/tmsearch.aspx?tn=146710314&st=Wordmark.

I tried internet and few combinations to test and generate this number but did not succeed. Is there any ways we can figure out a way to find the final URL request? I will the use this and make a request using Requests package.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the Search button, a request is sent to https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/tmrpublicsearch/frmmain.aspx. It's not a `GET` request.

The input data (Wordmark, class) is sent to this URL as a `POST` request. You need to `POST` this as form data (You can find all the fields in the network tab) on this URL.

The final script would look like this:

```py
import requests

session = requests.Session()

formData = {
    ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TBWordmark:'Wordmark'
    ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TBClass: 9

    #There are many other fields you need to include.
    #Go to Network Tab > Form Data
}

response = session.post(URL = "https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/tmrpublicsearch/frmmain.aspx"
, data = formData)

response = session.get("https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/tmrpublicsearch/tmsearch.aspx?tn=146710314&st=Wordmark")
# Send this `GET` request in the same session.
```

Note: You might need to send headers as well.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried this and used all the form data needed But i am getting the HTML content of the Form itself in response. My most basic inputs are wordmark (apple) and class(9). Other hidden input data is being generated automatically. number (146710314) is being generated automatically, using this data.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 requests involved first send the get request to the base URL and then get all the data and once done send the post request with all the form data and allow redirects cause when saw i it in the network tab it does a redirect to your specified URL like this one `https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/tmrpublicsearch/tmsearch.aspx?tn=146710314&st=Wordmark`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

s = requests.session()
Wordmark="Apple"
Class="9"

step1 = s.get("https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/tmrpublicsearch/frmmain.aspx")
soup = bs(step1.content, "html.parser")
__VIEWSTATE = soup.find('input', {'name': '__VIEWSTATE'})["value"]
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = soup.find('input', {'name': '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'})["value"]
__EVENTVALIDATION = soup.find('input', {'name': '__EVENTVALIDATION'})["value"]

formData = {
    "ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField": ";;AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.40412.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e:en-US:acfc7575-cdee-46af-964f-5d85d9cdcf92:475a4ef5:effe2a26:3ac3e789:5546a2b:d2e10b12:37e2e5c9:5a682656:bfe70f69",
    "__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$BtnSearch",
    "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
    "__VIEWSTATE": __VIEWSTATE,
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
    "__SCROLLPOSITIONX": "0",
    "__SCROLLPOSITIONY": "0",
    "__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED": "",
    "__EVENTVALIDATION": __EVENTVALIDATION,
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLSearchType": "WM",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLFilter": "0",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TBWordmark": Wordmark,
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$VCERFVTBWordmark_ClientState": "",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$VCEREVTBWordmark_ClientState": "",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TBVienna": "",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$VCERFVTBVienna_ClientState": "",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$VCEREVTBVienna_ClientState": "",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TBPhonetic": "",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$VCERFVTBPhonetic_ClientState": "",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$VCEREVTBPhonetic_ClientState": "",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TBClass": Class,
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$VCERFVTBClass_ClientState": "",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$VCERVTBClass_ClientState": ""
}
step2 = s.post("https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/tmrpublicsearch/frmmain.aspx", data=formData, allow_redirects=True)
print(step2.url) #url like https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/tmrpublicsearch/tmsearch.aspx?tn=201018220&st=Wordmark
#print(step.text)
#step2.content will contain the data for above like url so dont call again use above response to parse and generate data with BeautifulSoup.
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Let me know if you have any questions :)